# How to Set Data Label Number Format for an Area Chart in Google Sheets with App Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, charts

I have an Area chart in google sheets, embedded in a spreadsheet. In the Chart Editor, can edit the Data Label / Number Format property for some series to a Custom Format (in the example below I chose Custom for Number format and typed "Data label format"):

[image]

Is there a way to set this Data Label Number Format in App Script? When I update the chart from an AppScript, the Number Format is apparently reset to the default.

Presumably this would be done in a setOption, but which one? annotation?

```
var chart = sheet.getCharts()[0];
  chart = chart.modify()
    .setOption('vAxes', ...)
    .setOption([???])
    .build();
  sheet.updateChart(chart);
```

The google documentation in the series section says to look at "annotations" options but I can't seem to find them...

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/chart-configuration-options#area-config-options

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `edit the Data Label / Number Format property for some series to a Custom Format`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: @Tanaike, sorry for the delay, I have added a picture, I hope it helps clarify

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your expected result. Your added image is your input situation or your output situation?

Comment: @vsnn Did you ever figure this out? I cant find a way either. Even the macro builder code doesn't work.

Comment: @Tanaike In a Google Sheet chart, you can add data labels to line charts. For the data labels, in the UI you can set the number format of the data label. We're trying to set the number format using GAS.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan I am waiting for OP's response. But, I have no response. By this, I cannot know the sample input and output situations. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the OP's question. So, I cannot think of the OP's issue and goal. I apologize for this situation. For example, if you can provide a sample Spreadsheet for testing it, I will confirm it and I can search whether a solution is existing.

Comment: @Tanaike You can use https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t8BYQ65bc4unWXu_7po4Hcfn52VmBF5pfih2O2blet0/edit#gid=0 as an example. You'll notice in the chart, the line has data lables that are formatted as accounting. Using GAS, change the formattingn of the chart to something else. Don't change the number format of the source data (column C) -- change of the data label on the chart itself.

Comment: @IMTheNachoMan Thank you for replying. The chart in your provided Spreadsheet is the sample output situation? If it's so, can you provide the sample input situation? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand what you want to do and `Using GAS, change the formattingn of the chart to something else.`. I apologize for this. First, I would like to correctly understand your question.